# Question regarding absolute values in limits

Tags: calculus

I would like to ask a question regarding the absolute values in limits, since it seems that sometimes the absolute value is omitted, which I don't completely understand.

We are given the following limit:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h^2 \cdot \sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{h^2}})}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} h \cdot \sin(\frac{1}{h})$$

By squeeze theorem, we then have
$$-\lvert h \rvert \leq h \cdot \sin(\frac{1}{h}) \leq \lvert h \rvert $$
$$\lim_{h \to 0} h\cdot \sin(\frac{1}{h}) = 0$$

However, why can you equate the following two limits in the first place:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h^2 \cdot \sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{h^2}})}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} h \cdot \sin(\frac{1}{h})$$

The two limits aren't exactly equal to each other right? Since

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h^2 \cdot \sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{h^2}})}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} h \cdot \sin(\frac{1}{\lvert h \rvert})$$

So why can you simply omit the absolute value? Doesn't that change the solution (with the squeeze theorem)?

Comment: You should add the absolute sign but you've essentially proved that $|h\sin(1/h)|\leq|h|$ whatever the argument of sine you still have $|\sin(a)|\leq 1$

Comment: This is probably a typo in your textbook. The correct solution should use the absolute value signs or just leave it as $\sqrt{h^2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $ \sqrt{h^2}=|h|,$ hence

$$\frac{h^2 \cdot \sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{h^2}})}{h} =  h \cdot \sin(\frac{1}{\lvert h \rvert})$$

for $h \ne 0.$

From

$$ \lvert h \sin(\frac{1}{\lvert h \rvert}) \rvert \le |h|$$

we get

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h^2 \cdot \sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{h^2}})}{h} = 0.$$